# Session in JSP using Annotated Controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am storing a value in the session, from my Spring MVC Controller, this way:

```
@RequestMapping("usuario/getbyname")
public ModelAndView getByName(@ModelAttribute("user")Usuario user, HttpServletRequest request)
{

    ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("username", "nouser");
    model.setViewName("home");
    return model;
}
```

Then, in the JSP:

```
Value in session: ${sessionScope.username}
```

But nothing shows up in the JSP. What am I doing wrong? thank you.

EDIT:

Descriptor (servlet-context.xml, root-context is empty):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">


    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
        <!--  <beans:bean class="my.package.Controllers.LoginController"></beans:bean>-->
    <beans:bean class="my.package.Controllers.NewUserFormController"></beans:bean>
    <beans:bean class="my.package.Controllers.QueEsController"></beans:bean>
    <beans:bean class="my.package.Services.UsuarioServiceImp"></beans:bean>
    <beans:bean class="my.package.Dao.UserDaoImp">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myscheme"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="username" value="root"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="password" value="root"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

       <context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />

</beans:beans>
```

The method in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping("usuario/getbyname")
public ModelAndView getByName(@ModelAttribute("user")Usuario user, HttpServletRequest request){
    Usuario userFromDB;
    ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView();


    userFromDB=usuarioService.getUserByName(user.nombre);
    if(userFromDB==null){

        request.getSession().setAttribute("username", "nouser");
        model.setViewName("home");
        return model;
    }


        if(user.getNombre().equals(userFromDB.getNombre())&& user.getPass().equals(userFromDB.getPass())){

        model.addObject("login", "ok");
        model.addObject("usuario", user.getNombre());
        model.setViewName("home");

        return model;
        }else{

            model.addObject("login", "nopass");
            model.setViewName("home");
            return model;
        }

    }
```

Relevant part of the JSP:

```
<form action="usuario/getbyname" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <label class="textform">Nombre de usuario:</label>                  
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="nombre"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <label class="textform">Password:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="password" name="pass">         
        </td>       
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </td>
        <td class="textform">
        <a href="<c:url value="/newuserform" />" >Regístrate</a>
        <a href="<c:url value="/lostpass" />" >Recuperar contraseña</a>
        </td>
    </tr>



</table>    
</form>

<P>  The time on the server is ${serverTime}. </P>
<P> blablablablabla</P>
<p>Username: ${sessionScope.username}.
```

The JSP is at webapp/web-inf/views

Comment: Sorry, updating the code

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you sure that EL expression is in the view resolved from `home`?

Comment: It is home.jsp. but two strange things happens: the url shown in the navigator is the one thas in in the @RequestMapping (usuario/getbyname) and in the JSP there is another EL expression (${serverTime}). And this doesnt shows neither. i have to say: the user is presented home.jsp, and the servertime shows ok. Then the user tries to log-in, the Controller works (Service, then DAO tries to get the user from the DB) and THEN is when that piece of code works. And the servertime dissapears.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example we can try? This would include your deployment descriptor, Spring configuration, controller class, and JSP and its location.

Comment: On my way, will update the question.

Comment: I had to comment the LoginController bean declaration (which is the Controller involved in this piece of code) to avoid ambiguous declaration, because of <context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />

Comment: You don't need explicit `<bean>` declarations if you have `component-scan` over those packages and the classes are annotated with `@Controller`.

Comment: Your attribute is only set in the `if` block. Are you sure that's being executed?

Comment: I have some sysouts I havent posted and those sysouts are showing. And yes, the class is annotated with @Controller, otherwise it would not work at all

Comment: I don't know...Try debugging the whole thing. Step through your controller code, step through Spring's MVC stack until the `DispatcherServlet` forwards to your JSP.

Comment: Maybe is the request object? Its not initialized, just passed as an argument in the method. But not sure its a functional object.

Comment: No, Spring takes the `HttpServletRequest` passed to its `DispatcherServlet#service(..)` method and passes it as an argument when it invokes your handler method through reflection.

Comment: The method originally didnt had the HttpServletRequest, I added it manually, to access the session object. Don't know if that is relevant.

Comment: It's a perfectly fine argument to a handler method.

Comment: Can I add a text in the session from the JSP? That is the only thing I need to add, if I cannot do it from the Controller, maybe I can do it in the JSP...

Comment: You could, but I don't recommend it. I'd like yo to try one more thing. Instead of using the `HttpServletRequest`, add a `@Autowired` annotated `HttpSession` field to your controller and try to add the attribute through that directly.

Comment: Didn't worked. I didnt declared the bean in the descriptor, however, but you said it isn't necessary. Its correct?

Comment: You don't need to declare a bean for it anywhere. When you say it didn't work, do you mean initialization failed or you simply don't see the attribute in JSP?

Comment: Initialization was ok,(no exceptions) but didnt see the attribute.

Comment: Im going to look for a way to add it from the JSP. Dont want to waste more of your time. Thanks for your help, my friend.

Comment: Hehe, don't worry, that's what we're here for. I would suggest you try a bare-bones controller that simply adds something to the session and returns a view that tries to access that. If it works, then your problem is elsewhere. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am using it in different way (and it works fine):

```
@Component
@Scope (value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class UserSessionObject implements Serializable {
    //PUT HERE YOUR VARIABLES
}


@Controller
@RequestMapping ("/product")
public class Advertise {
    @Autowired
    private UserSessionObject userSessionObject;

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    //DO YOUR CTL STUFF HERE

    mv.addObject("session", userSessionObject);
    return mv;
}
```

Spring must pick up those 2 classes.

In your JSP you can use ${session.yourThing}